# How did research reproducibility in medicine evolve over time?

Tags: academia, publishing, medicine, scientific-method

Some recent studies have analyzed the percentage of research that is [reproducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducibility).
E.g. *Prinz, F.; Schlange, T.; Asadullah, K. (2011). "[Believe it or not: How much can we rely on published data on potential drug targets?](http://www.nature.com/nrd/journal/v10/n9/full/nrd3439-c1.html)". Nature Reviews Drug Discovery 10 (9): 712. doi:10.1038/nrd3439-c1. PMID 21892149.* found that found that 65% of medical studies were inconsistent when re-tested, and only 6% were completely reproducible.

I wonder how research reproducibility in medicine has evolved over time.

Comment: Right now, this question seems awfully broad to me. Could you perhaps make it a little more specific, focusing on either one particular aspect, one period of time, one discipline (medicine?) or something similar?

Comment: @Danu Thanks for the suggestion, sounds good, let's restrict the question to the medicine field!